# How to save cURL response into a file?

Tags: curl

I already managed to save cookie file using CURLOPT_COOKIEFILE and CURLOPT_COOKIEJAR
it's saving info normally
now i'm trying to save response data into a file or inside that cookie
how is it possible ?

Note for easier answer : the response is simply written in print through IF
how can i include something that can store the print data into a file

Comment: Welcome to stack overflow. To get a useful answer here, you need to first show you have tried solving your problem and second be more specific. Questions that require a book to answer are not fit for this website. If you include some important code and pin down where exactly is your problem, you'll more easily get an answer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
$file = fopen("MyFile.txt", 'w+'); // Create a new file, or overwrite the existing one.
fwrite($file, $dataFromCurl);
fclose($file);
```

Please read the PHP manual. Most basic questions, such as file operation is explained there:
http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.fopen.php